# SSAS Data Source View Variable

Tags: t-sql, variables, ssas, dataview

I'm trying to use "New Named Query" to add a table in Data Source View in SSAS. The script is shown as follows:

```
Declare @AvgInvestment float;
SELECT  @AvgInvestment=SUM(Investment)/COUNT(distinct meta_ID)
FROM AAAA



SELECT        Player, Investment, 
              InvestmentRange=
              Case When Investment >=0 AND  Investment <(@AvgInvestment/3)                       THEN 1
                   When Investment >=(@AvgInvestment/3) AND  Investment <(4*@AvgInvestment/3)    THEN 2                           
                   When Investment >=(4*@AvgInvestment/3) AND  Investment <(6*@AvgInvestment/3)  THEN 3                         
                   When Investment >=(2*@AvgInvestment)                                          THEN 4
             END                              
FROM  AAAA
```

However, SSAS does not allow declare variables in SQL Query for DVS.  Is there any possible way to modify the SQL statement to have no variables?  I tried to replace @AvgInvestment as "SELECT SUM(Investment)/COUNT(distinct meta_ID) FROM AAAA" , but it's not working.

Thanks for any possible solutions!

Comment: Don't remember if possible in Data Source views in SSAS, but you might try using stored procedure to get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join with your average instead using variable. For example:

```
SELECT Player, Investment, 
       InvestmentRange=
       Case When Investment >=0 AND  Investment <(a.avg/3)              THEN 1
            When Investment >=(a.avg/3) AND  Investment <(4*a.avg/3)    THEN 2
            When Investment >=(4*a.avg/3) AND  Investment <(6*a.avg/3)  THEN 3                         
            When Investment >=(2*a.avg)                                 THEN 4
       END                               
FROM  AAAA cross join 
(select SUM(Investment)/COUNT(distinct meta_ID) as avg from aaaa) a
```

Works perfectly in Data Source view. Stored procedures won't work there.